# Liquibase looks for a strange path, when loading data from csv and throws an error

Tags: java, spring, csv, h2, liquibase

Liquibase version: 4.7

The path that liquibase is looking for is a combination between the changeset path and the csv content.

**Error message**

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/v2_1_data_update.xml::20210206-1_local::beng:
     Reason: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <"> at index 30: config/liquibase/changelog\[{ "attId": 0, "refSystem": "MOXIS",
```

**Change set for loading the data, that is failing:**

```
 <changeSet id="20210206-1_local" author="beng" context="dev" dbms="h2">
        <comment>load moxis documents test data for internal users 21-30</comment>
        <loadData encoding="UTF-8"
                  file="config/liquibase/csv/dev/documentsmoxis_devh2.csv"
                  separator=";"
                  tableName="document">
            <column name="visible_until" type="datetime"/>
            <column name="document_date" type="date"/>
            <column name="expires_on" type="datetime"/>
            <column name="form" type="boolean"/>
            <column name="check_processed" type="boolean"/>
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>
```

**Adding the last 3 columns to the table:**

```
<changeSet id="20210204-1" author="beng">
        <comment>Adding action_required,ref_system,attachments columns to table document</comment>
        <addColumn tableName="document">
            <column name="action_required" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="ref_system" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="attachments" type="clob">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
```

Csv file, from where the data is loaded

[image: csv file]

Answer (score 1):

If my memory serves me right LB considers column config in changeset as a "hint", but the real load scenario is based on column config, table metadata and CVS, in your case `attachments` column is present in table and has LOB type, so LB assumes that you are trying to load LOB from file. Try explicitly exclude `attachments` column from loading:

```xml
<column name="attachments" type="skip"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Afte excluding attachments I now receive following error message:

liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/v2_1_data_update.xml::20210206-1_local::beng:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Invalid value "31" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-200]

Comment: @ggeorgia that error seems to be specific for H2, LB and your setup, try to run LB with FINE log level (https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/log-level.html) in order to understand what it tries to execute